# Do I need to encrypt 2FA Authenticator Key generated by Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I am implementing MFA for a website by using ASP.NET Core Identity.
Unlike the standard implementation, the Identity User data is stored in the website Database
(rather than in a dedicated Identity one in a standard implementation)

I based my implementation on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0) using [this sample code](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreHybridFlowWithApi) as a reference.

In the [EnableAuthenticator page](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreHybridFlowWithApi/blob/main/IdentityStandaloneMfa/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator.cshtml.cs) which generate the Authenticator code
the following code generates a new Authenticator key and saves it to the Database:

`await _userManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);`

My question is - is it worth to encrypt/hash this key instead of storing it in the Database 'as is'?

What is the possibility that someone (a hacker) uses this key to register in his own Authenticator app, then generate the 6-digit passcode and log in?

So far I've tried to take the authenticator key and manually create an entry in another Authenticator app on my phone (I didn't try to use different phones yet).
I was able to log in this way, which seem to suggest that stealing a key might be enough to log in
(obviously one also needs to know the username and password!)

Comment: From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0) we can see "FIDO2 is currently :  The most secure way of achieving MFA.
The only MFA flow that protects against phishing attacks." You can read [Passwordless authentication options for Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-passwordless)  to know more.